# Connect to MySQL using SqlAlchemy with \ in server name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need connect to MySQL database using SQLAlchemy, but I can`t do it, because server name name contains ""(my server name = "datawarehouse\dwh"). How I can fix it?

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'datawarehouse\\dwh' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")

Comment: Is that server at a windows network address, generally written starting with \\?

Comment: i don`t know, honesty

Comment: It is very common to see a Microsoft SQL Server instance name with a backslash. I've never seen a MySQL server name with a backslash because those names correspond to Internet DNS names like `dwh.example.com` and they (almost?) never use backslashes. So: Are you sure that this is a MySQL server?

Comment: Yes, because i can connect to DB using pymysql by next parameters:conn = pymssql.connect(server='datawarehouse\dwh', user='pynative', password='pynative', database='АЗ')

Comment: You say that you're using pymysql, but you are calling `pymssql.connect()`